How do I convert numbers to subscripts in a chemical equation using Dart, when preceded by letters, subscripts, or a right parenthesis?
I'm trying to write a Dart function that converts numbers in a chemical equation to subscripts, but only if they are preceded by a letter, another subscript, or a right parenthesis ).
For example, given the input:
2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O
I want the second, third, and fifth occurrences of the number 2 to be converted to subscripts, resulting in:
2H₂ + O₂ -> 2H₂O
Similarly, in cases like (H2O)3, the result should be (H₂O)₃. I’m having difficulty with the implementation and properly identifying the conditions where a number should be converted.
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this in Dart would be greatly appreciated!

You could use look-behind to check what the preceding character is and require it is a digit, letter or closing parenthesis: (?<=[\w)])\d.
Call replaceAllMapped to get all matches, and use the callback function to convert the matched digit to the corresponding subscript. As the Unicode code points for the subscript characters are in a sequential range from 8320 to 8329, we can translate each digit by simply adding a constant to their code point:
final result = inputstr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(?<=[\w)])\d'), (match) {
    return String.fromCharCode(match[0]!.codeUnitAt(0) + 8272);
});

The number 8272 is the code point distance between "0" (48) and "₀" (8320).
